# Calculate year-on-year percent change for weekly frequency data using Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Suppose we have data `df` with weekly frequency as follows:

```
           date       x1     x2       x3        y
0      2010-1-3      NaN  368.5  75.6927  21.1136
1     2010-1-10   81.096  368.5  22.3010  12.3962
2     2010-1-17   78.702  368.5  22.5899   0.0000
3     2010-1-24   75.692  368.5  84.8835  42.2456
4     2010-1-31   72.562  368.5  53.3456  53.3456
..          ...      ...    ...      ...      ...
99   2011-11-27  107.422  375.0   1.5194   0.0000
100   2011-12-4  109.854  375.0   2.9112   0.0000
101  2011-12-11  109.376  375.0  21.9538  18.3002
102  2011-12-18  106.044  375.0  41.4685   0.0000
103  2011-12-25  106.786  365.0  12.6816   0.0000
```

I know that the annual percentage change is generally for monthly or quarterly data, but now I want to calculate the year-on-year percent change of all `X` columns in this data? We know that some years have 52 weeks and others have 53 weeks. May I ask how to achieve it? Thanks.

**Complete data available for testing:**

```
           date        x1     x2        x3         y
0      2010-1-3       NaN  368.5   75.6927   21.1136
1     2010-1-10   81.0960  368.5   22.3010   12.3962
2     2010-1-17   78.7020  368.5   22.5899    0.0000
3     2010-1-24   75.6920  368.5   84.8835   42.2456
4     2010-1-31   72.5620  368.5   53.3456   53.3456
5      2010-2-7   73.3620  368.5    0.0000    0.0000
6     2010-2-14   72.1460  368.5   25.8555   25.8555
7     2010-2-21   76.0860  368.5    0.0000    0.0000
8     2010-2-28   77.5660  368.5   72.0376    0.0000
9      2010-3-7   78.5500  368.5   30.8786    0.0000
10    2010-3-14   80.1060  368.5   12.5903    0.0000
11    2010-3-21   80.0460  366.5   77.1834    0.0000
12    2010-3-28   79.9520  366.5    0.0000    0.0000
13     2010-4-4   82.2900  366.5   41.6271   41.6271
14    2010-4-11   85.4520  369.5    0.0000    0.0000
15    2010-4-18   85.7600  369.5   44.4081    0.0000
16    2010-4-25   85.5300  369.5   23.7169   23.7169
17     2010-5-2   86.6220  375.5    0.0000    0.0000
18     2010-5-9   83.0640  375.5   83.4840   65.6898
19    2010-5-16   79.8200  375.5   24.9747    7.5562
20    2010-5-23   73.3480  375.5   77.8106    0.0000
21    2010-5-30   72.2280  375.5    7.3379    0.0000
22     2010-6-6   73.7220  375.5   30.9534   30.9534
23    2010-6-13   73.6660  375.5   11.3257   11.3257
24    2010-6-20   77.2880  379.5   26.1935   26.1935
25    2010-6-27   77.5440  375.5   10.1233    0.0000
26     2010-7-4   74.4060  375.5   43.3410   30.4283
27    2010-7-11   73.3120  375.5   20.5102    0.0000
28    2010-7-18   75.8700  375.5    0.0000    0.0000
29    2010-7-25   76.4960  375.5   23.5228   12.9511
30     2010-8-1   77.0920  375.5   12.9771    0.0000
31     2010-8-8   81.4940  372.5   10.9894   10.9894
32    2010-8-15   77.7720  372.5   16.6029   16.6029
33    2010-8-22   75.5620  372.5   44.8074   14.2747
34    2010-8-29   74.2300  372.5   17.3201   13.3601
35     2010-9-5   76.2380  372.5   42.9619   41.6567
36    2010-9-12   77.6820  372.5   34.8467   15.0840
37    2010-9-19   78.7580  372.5    0.4776    0.0000
38    2010-9-26   78.5340  377.0   32.1695    4.3874
39    2010-10-3   80.8220  377.0   69.5636   46.2733
40   2010-10-10   84.1280  377.0    0.0000    0.0000
41   2010-10-17   83.7680  387.0    0.9515    0.9515
42   2010-10-24   82.7720  387.0   15.9094   15.0731
43   2010-10-31   83.4340  390.0    0.0000    0.0000
44    2010-11-7   86.5040  390.0  138.5893  122.3192
45   2010-11-14   88.1800  403.0    9.3737    1.7383
46   2010-11-21   84.8200  403.0   89.9526    0.0000
47   2010-11-28   84.9460  409.0   75.4948   22.6395
48    2010-12-5   88.8480  423.0  117.0465  103.8658
49   2010-12-12   91.0160  423.0   70.1997   28.2743
50   2010-12-19   91.5960  423.0   63.6496    0.0000
51   2010-12-26   93.5220  423.0  132.6323   19.7902
52     2011-1-2   94.0420  423.0  186.9060   77.4868
53     2011-1-9   94.3440  423.0   12.0977    7.0043
54    2011-1-16   97.6340  401.0   28.1320   28.1320
55    2011-1-23   97.5140  401.0    0.0000    0.0000
56    2011-1-30   97.3160  401.0   56.0128   24.2362
57     2011-2-6  101.3360  401.0   21.1012   21.1012
58    2011-2-13  100.6580  401.0    0.0000    0.0000
59    2011-2-20  102.7220  401.0    3.0778    0.0000
60    2011-2-27  109.2540  391.0   33.0948    3.6520
61     2011-3-6  114.8660  391.0    0.0000    0.0000
62    2011-3-13  114.6620  391.0   35.1084   15.6646
63    2011-3-20  112.3280  387.0  107.8492  107.8492
64    2011-3-27  115.5040  387.0    0.0000    0.0000
65     2011-4-3  116.2300  408.0    5.0935    3.5436
66    2011-4-10  122.9800  408.0   51.9346   51.9346
67    2011-4-17  122.7180  414.0   20.2421   13.0763
68    2011-4-24  122.6950  426.0    7.1284    0.0000
69     2011-5-1  124.7680  426.0   14.4348    0.0000
70     2011-5-8  117.7380  426.0   24.1443    0.0000
71    2011-5-15  114.5820  426.0   25.0530    0.0000
72    2011-5-22  111.7660  426.0   14.5387   14.5387
73    2011-5-29  113.5280  427.0   39.6820   37.3242
74     2011-6-5  115.4640  427.0   37.0821   37.0821
75    2011-6-12  117.4920  411.0    4.1271    0.0000
76    2011-6-19  116.7180  411.0   86.5525   25.0954
77    2011-6-26  109.8460  393.0   51.7524   42.0237
78     2011-7-3  110.2840  393.0   21.4058   16.1309
79    2011-7-10  115.1080  388.0    6.5475    0.0000
80    2011-7-17  117.8700  388.0    0.7956    0.7956
81    2011-7-24  117.4880  388.0   31.3416    0.0000
82    2011-7-31  117.5500  388.0    3.7789    0.0000
83     2011-8-7  112.6240  388.0   12.9591    6.7814
84    2011-8-14  105.8080  388.0   86.4462   30.8959
85    2011-8-21  109.1180  385.0   52.0589   10.7045
86    2011-8-28  109.9600  385.0    1.4449    0.0000
87     2011-9-4  113.4740  385.0   37.6492   16.8879
88    2011-9-11  113.2180  385.0   12.0605    0.0000
89    2011-9-18  112.8200  385.0   23.3209    0.0000
90    2011-9-25  107.9000  379.0   44.2941   21.4235
91    2011-10-2  104.3200  379.0   28.1059    2.3386
92    2011-10-9  103.1680  379.0   13.8519    9.7453
93   2011-10-16  111.3660  379.0   20.4978    9.0089
94   2011-10-23  109.8040  379.0   18.2043   11.6179
95   2011-10-30  110.6540  379.0   29.7843   29.7843
96    2011-11-6  110.2480  379.0   46.3519    4.4620
97   2011-11-13  113.9480  375.0   34.6809    2.9529
98   2011-11-20  110.3880  375.0   54.0846   38.5976
99   2011-11-27  107.4220  375.0    1.5194    0.0000
100   2011-12-4  109.8540  375.0    2.9112    0.0000
101  2011-12-11  109.3760  375.0   21.9538   18.3002
102  2011-12-18  106.0440  375.0   41.4685    0.0000
103  2011-12-25  106.7860  365.0   12.6816    0.0000
104    2012-1-1  108.0550  361.0   52.7528   22.4153
105    2012-1-8  112.9075  361.0    8.3129    0.0000
106   2012-1-15  111.9340  361.0   23.7668   19.2656
107   2012-1-22  110.9600  361.0   42.0616   27.9204
108   2012-1-29  110.5340  361.0    0.0000    0.0000
109    2012-2-5  111.9880  361.0   16.6643   16.6643
110   2012-2-12  117.0520  361.0   12.6662    0.0000
111   2012-2-19  118.9420  366.0   20.9504    1.7893
112   2012-2-26  122.7400  366.0   23.7619   23.7619
113    2012-3-4  123.6460  362.0    3.8019    3.8019
114   2012-3-11  124.2640  362.0    0.0000    0.0000
115   2012-3-18  125.1780  378.0    3.8351    0.0000
116   2012-3-25  124.4600  378.0   18.0393   16.6881
117    2012-4-1  124.1240  378.0   15.6201    4.1409
118    2012-4-8  124.0150  378.0    0.0000    0.0000
119   2012-4-15  121.2540  379.0   19.2779   10.4958
120   2012-4-22  118.4380  381.0   44.7349   40.0032
121   2012-4-29  119.1480  381.0    5.2782    5.2782
122    2012-5-6  117.3180  377.0    0.0000    0.0000
123   2012-5-13  112.8160  367.0    0.0000    0.0000
124   2012-5-20  110.0300  365.0    4.1888    4.1888
125   2012-5-27  107.2320  365.0    2.9826    2.9826
126    2012-6-3  103.5120  361.0    4.9081    4.9081
127   2012-6-10   99.5460  353.0    3.7699    3.7699
128   2012-6-17   97.3820  353.0    2.7117    1.2502
129   2012-6-24   92.9420  345.0    5.0907    3.8954
130    2012-7-1   93.3380  345.0   19.9281   19.9281
131    2012-7-8   99.3360  317.0   12.5955   12.5955
132   2012-7-15  100.0400  301.0   10.0260    6.1391
133   2012-7-22  105.4680  300.0   52.0001    5.3489
134   2012-7-29  104.5580  299.0    7.9663    7.9663
135    2012-8-5  106.3840  303.0    0.6018    0.0000
136   2012-8-12  111.9720  303.0    0.0000    0.0000
137   2012-8-19  114.8980  303.0   25.6048   19.4946
138   2012-8-26  114.3700  303.0    0.0000    0.0000
139    2012-9-2  112.9200  298.0  150.4855  150.4855
140    2012-9-9  114.1580  290.0    0.0000    0.0000
141   2012-9-16  115.9460  293.0   24.4552    0.0000
142   2012-9-23  111.0920  291.0   35.5393   11.9281
143   2012-9-30  110.9400  302.0   91.0435   16.7387
144   2012-10-7  111.3060    NaN    0.0000    0.0000
145  2012-10-14  114.1960  300.0   12.0410   12.0410
146  2012-10-21  113.3300  302.0    9.0401    9.0401
147  2012-10-28  108.7160  300.0    4.1426    4.1426
148   2012-11-4  108.2140  296.0   28.4039   24.0981
149  2012-11-11  108.4540  301.0   23.8801    0.0000
150  2012-11-18  109.3740  305.0    0.0000    0.0000
151  2012-11-25  110.8640  306.0    0.0000    0.0000
152   2012-12-2  110.4580  306.0   32.9348    0.0000
153   2012-12-9  108.7240  306.0    8.1277    0.0000
154  2012-12-16  108.3800  306.0    7.6854    0.0000
155  2012-12-23  109.2020  306.0   62.8203   62.8203
156  2012-12-30  110.3225  306.0   63.9954   47.1066
```

Comment: No of weeks should not be concern for you, You aggregate the data at yearly level and calculate pct change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract the week and year with [isocalendar](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.isocalendar.html#pandas.Series.dt.isocalendar),

```
isocalendar = df['date'].dt.isocalendar()

(df.drop('date',axis=1).assign(**isocalendar[['year','week']])
   .set_index(['year','week'])
   .stack().unstack('week')
   .groupby(level=1).pct_change()
   .stack().unstack(level=1)
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand, how does your code handle the situation that the previous year is 52 weeks and this year is 53 weeks? Also is it possible to calculate the YoY percentage change only for `x1`, `x2`, `x3`? The new dataset will still have `date` (or `year` and `week`), `x1`, `x2`, `x3` and `y` columns.

Comment: the 53 week will be `NaN` most of the time. the new data set still has year and week, which can  be used to map back the old `date` column.